# Uploading custom cls file

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, mwe

A lot of the time the questions I ask on the TeX stack exchange regard projects using specific class/style files (.cls, .clo, .sty, fonts, etc.). My approach to these questions has been to provide the relevant TeX code in the question and set up an online TeX repository (on Overleaf, repl.it, tutorialspoint, or similar online services), which functions as a MWE, containing all the relevant files. However, people on SE dislike outside links for various reasons.

What is the norm here for such questions? I don't see a way to upload the files to the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

It is very rare to need an entire custom class. Almost always you can use a standard class, or failing that a publicly available class, and add whatever custom code is needed to the preamble of the test file.

Making such a file helps narrow down the problem for anyone trying to help and protects the question (which is archived forever) from changes at an external link such as an overleaf project